# how to set action on netbeans save items?

Tags: java, netbeans, ant

Im trying to run my own exe program on compile action in netbeans java project.`

I tried to add exec action to precompile phase of a build-impl.xml file in netbeans, like this:

```
<target name="-pre-compile">
        <!-- Empty placeholder for easier customization. -->
        <!-- You can override this target in the ../build.xml file. -->
        <echo level="info">START EXEC PRECOMPILE</echo>
        <exec executable="${basedir}\execFolder\program.exe"/>
        <echo level="info">END EXEC PRECOMPILE</echo>
    </target>
```

and it is fired on build action or build and clean action but it is not fired on save action.

Altough I have checked Compile on save option in my project options.

Any idea how to ensure the program to be fired on save action?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: R U sure "compile on save" is calling the Ant build file? The IDE use compiling to provide features like syntax checking, and I don't think it would use a project's build file to do that. You may need to write some Netbeans plugin to do that.

Comment: thats exactly what am I trying to do, what would you do to reach that functionality?

Comment: Personally I will check Netbeans plugin sdk...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do it easily. "Compile on save" is not using ant. See [FAQ on CoS](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqCompileOnSave#When_CoS_is_not_appropriate)

> The Compile on Save cannot be used in some specific cases. For example:
>
> - The build script contains additional actions added by the user which
>     are necessary for running the application. CoS does not use Ant to
>     launch applications so these additional task would not be performed.

You would have to write a NB module implementing [OnSaveTask](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-modules-editor-lib2/org/netbeans/spi/editor/document/OnSaveTask.html) and registering OnSaveTask.Factory. See this post blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/save_actions_in_netbeans_ide (all the way down).

Comment: Do you have in mind any other way how to perform my own action on save  ?

Comment: I think you have to create a NB module implementing OnSaveTask.Factory. See this post https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/save_actions_in_netbeans_ide (all the way down).